# How to evaluate limit of a user-defined function

Tags: functions, evaluation

```
Limit[(k/(k - 1)), k -> Infinity]
```

Gives correctly:

```
1
```

But,

```
L[k_Integer] := (k/(k - 1))
Limit[L[k], k -> Infinity]
```

leaves the limit unevaluated.

How can I tell Mathematica to evaluate this limit?

Comment: Remove "Integer"

Comment: Moreover, DiscreteLimit[L[k], k -> Infinity] is unevaluated too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input restriction means it is basically not amenable to analysis by `Limit` or even `DiscreteLimit`. If instead it is defined piecewise then the sequence limit can be found.

```
lL[k_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(k/(k - 1)), Element[k, Integers]}, {Indeterminate, 
    True}}]
DiscreteLimit[lL[k], k -> Infinity]

(* Out[113]= 1 *)
```